# Filter Criteria1 and Criteria 2 undefined on column of Dates

Tags: excel, vba, filter

According to Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter.criteria2 It is possible to set a variable = .Criteria2. This throws a runtime 1004 error in Excel 2010-2019/365.

Note: if the filtered column is dates, Criteria1 and Criteria2 are undefined: Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error.
Note: Excel will correctly remember Criteria1 when filtering a column of text or numbers.

To simplify this for reviewers, I simply recorded a macro filtering a column of dates and added comments to show the results.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
Dim testfilter As Variant
Dim testfilter2 As Variant

' I recorded filtering Column A and removing a few dates

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$51").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("=") _
        , Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "6/7/2021", 0, "10/27/2020", 0, _
        "11/16/2019", 1, "3/30/2018", 1, "5/17/2018", 1, "6/30/2018", 1, "7/28/2018", 1, _
        "9/3/2018", 1, "10/31/2018", 1, "12/29/2018")
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    With WS.AutoFilter
       With .Filters(1)
         If .On And .Operator Then
            testfilter = .Criteria1 ' Criteria1 = "="
            testfilter2 = .Criteria2 ' Runtime Error 1004 - Application-Defined or object-defined error
        End If
       End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Reread your link to .Criteria2 carefully and add the missing part (you check for Filter.On, but there is a second criteria to be met for Citeria2. Btw:. Criteria2 only applies if your filter needs one, like filter on between (dates, numbers)

Comment: Correct. Criteria2 filters dates. I can record a macro of filtering the dates in a column, but I cannot "remember" Criteria2 because it is undefined. That's my problem. The operator is 7 when filtering dates, so that won't help. My code is not the problem, the undefined variable is.

Comment: Please remove your edit with solution from question and add it as an answer!

Comment: That was not the solution. Still a problem.

Comment: No you just did a bad edit on var declaration! And you should loop all filters

Comment: After 25 years of using Excel VBA, I believe this is a bug in Excel. If you would try to do this yourself, filtering a column of dates then assigning the results to a variable, you will find that Criteria2 is undefined. If you have a solution that will allow me to assign Criteria2 to a variable that I can use later, I would be grateful.

Comment: You need a proper var not your crappy `testfilter2` array of variants!

Comment: Even if I change it to not an array, Criteria2 is not defined. Try it yourself. It's not a problem with my code. It's a problem with Criteria2 undefined..

Comment: I tried and it is defined (with proper values)! E.G. Crit1 and Crit2 needs to be connected by an operator (I used `xlAnd`). I can't test your filters as I lack the data, but just create a custom filter on a date col with 2 criterias (after 1.1.20) and (before 8.8.20).

Comment: Sorry if I pissed you off. I'm just trying to remember Criteria1 and Criteria2 after filtering on perhaps two dates within a month. I'm not using > date1 and < date2.. Excel executes it as shown above, but I can't seem to capture Criteria2. Then I can apply it correctly when I restore it. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: You filter by GUI in sheet? On any cell (e.g. text) chose "Filter -> Filter by selected cell value -> expand Filter Combobox -> Text Filter (or matching FilterType) -> Custom Filter (last option)" That opens Custom Autofilter Dialog where you can define 2 Criterias connected by And/Or. If second Criteria is populated you can read Filter.Critera2. If second crit is not set then Filter.Operator will be false and you can't read Criteria2.

Answer (score 3):

If one uses Excel’s date filters, Criteria1 and Criteria2 are defined and can be assigned to a variable so that they can be remembered and reapplied.

If one has dates from 2018 to 2020 and unchecks the box next to 2018 in the dropdown filter menu, Excel uses an array for Criteria2, but Criteria2 remains undefined and causes a Runtime Error 1004 if one tries to assign it to a variable.

Workaround: Require use of data filters and use code to detect and handle undefined Criteria1 and Criteria2.

I want to thank ComputerVersteher for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you ask Excel to return criteria 2, you get the second value of the array of criteria1.

```
Criteria1:=Array("=", Criteria2)
```

So, you can set

```
Criteria2:=Array(0, "6/7/2021", 0, "10/27/2020", ...
```

But that is not what is returned by Excel.

I know it has been a while since the last reply, but I wanted to share this fundamental info.